# Top Level element must be a map? YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, config

Im not quite sure what this aws error is trying to tell me, but i know my syntax must be off. I have run it through a YAML validator and it says it is valid. The full error is below

```
Top level element in configuration file .ebextensions/keys.config in application version First Release must be a map. Update the top level element in the configuration file.
```

Here is my YAML code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would also like to understand what exactly the error is trying to tell me.

```
"option_settings:option_name:AUTH_KEY value:'BLAH' - option_name:SECURE_AUTH_KEY value:'BLAH' - option_name:LOGGED_IN_KEY value:'BLAH' - option_name:NONCE_KEY value:'BLAH' - option_name:SECURE_AUTH_SALT value:'BLAH' - option_name:LOGGED_IN_SALT value:'BLAH' - option_name:NONCE_SALT value:'BLAH' - option_name:AUTH_SALT value:'BLAH'"
```

Comment: can you properly format the YAML?

Comment: i tried in the code block and it wouldn't let me.